# XSLT Select attribute value of node with another attribute with a given value

Tags: xslt

I have a large number of html files like the following 01.html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>My Title</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <item itemprop="itemprop1" content="content1" /> 
    <item itemprop="itemprop2" content="content2" /> 
    <item itemprop="itemprop3" content="content3" /> 
    <item itemprop="itemprop4" content="content4" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop5" content="content5" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop6" content="content6" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop7" content="content7" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop8" content="content8" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop9" content="content9" />
  </body>
</html>
```

There is only one item node with itemprop="itemprop1" in each html file. Same for itemprop2, itemprop3, etc.

I would like to have the following txt file output:

```
content1 | content 5
```

that is the concatenation of:
 1. the value of the attribute content for the item with itemprop="itemprop1" 
 2. a pipe "|" 
 3. the value of the attribute content for the item with itemprop="itemprop5"

I run the following bash script:

```
xsltproc 01.xslt 01.html >> 02.txt
```

where 01.xslt is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:value-of select="//item[@itemprop='itemprop1']/@content"/>|<xsl:value-of select="item[@itemprop='itemprop5']/@content"/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. What is the correct xslt file?

UPDATE

This is the final working example.

01.html is the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>My Title</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <item itemprop="itemprop1" content="content1" /> 
    <item itemprop="itemprop2" content="content2" /> 
    <item itemprop="itemprop3" content="content3" /> 
    <item itemprop="itemprop4" content="content4" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop5" content="content5" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop6" content="content6" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop7" content="content7" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop8" content="content8" />
    <item itemprop="itemprop9" content="content9" />
  </body>
</html>
```

01.xslt is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="html">
  <xsl:value-of select="//item[@itemprop='itemprop1']/@content"/>
  <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="//item[@itemprop='itemprop5']/@content"/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output 02.txt is the following:

```
content1|content5
```

Comment: What is being output that you do not want? Does it not work because it is outputting the title?

Comment: Your main problem using `xsltproc` is that you're trying to process HTML instead of XML. The difference is in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` tag which isn't closed and hence there is no valid XML for the XSLT processor (what results in an error).

Comment: @Wyatt Shipman: I do not understand why it is outputting the title after I closed the <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> tag. I'm matching "body" and selecting only items - why is outputting also the title, that is contained in "head"?

Comment: PS. now I understand why the title was outputted. I should have matched "html", not "body"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, XSTL processes **XML** files, not **HTML**.

Your source HTML **almost** meets requirements of well-formed
XML. There is only one error: Your `meta` element is not closed,
so I changed it to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

(adding `/` before the closing `>`).
Otherwise the XSLT processor displays an error message (at least in
my installation).

As far as your XSLT is concerned, I made a few corrections:

- `match="body"` changed to `match="html"`,
- added `//` in the second `xsl:value-of`,
- changed "bare" `|` to `<xsl:text>|</xsl:text>`, only for
  readability reason (longer lines can not be seen on smaller
  monitors),
- added `<xsl:output method="text"/>` as your output does not
  seem to be any XML.

Last 2 changes are optional, you can ignore them.

So the whole script can be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="html">
    <xsl:value-of select="//item[@itemprop='itemprop1']/@content"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="//item[@itemprop='itemprop5']/@content"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo. I have tried the changes that you suggested and in fact it now works. Thank you also for the 2 optional changes that I didn't know yet. As you are the first person to respond with a correct answer I'm going to select your answer as the correct one, although zx485's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem using `xsltproc` is that you're trying to process HTML instead of XML. The difference is in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` tag which isn't closed and hence there is no valid XML for the XSLT processor (what results in an error). So add a closing char to make it

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If you fix this problem and add a template that removes 'non-matching' `text()` nodes like

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

your XSLT will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you zx485. I was just about to update my question, because I noticed that my example did not have the closing slash in the meta line. My output however was "My Titlecontent1|content5". I have added the line to remove text() and now my output is correct "content1|content5". I still do not understand why text() is outputted thought. Could you give me a pointer please?

Comment: PS I found out why the title was outputted. I should have matched html, not body.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="html/body/item[@itemprop='itemprop1']/@content"/>|<xsl:value-of select="html/body/item[@itemprop='itemprop5']/@content"/>
    </xsl:template>
```